# rename fails on filenames with spaces

Tags: ksh

I have a KSH simple script that creates a list of files we receive on our FTP server.

```
sF_Array=(` find . -type f ...  `)
sF_len=${#sF_Array[*]}
for name in ${sF_Array[@]}
do
   basename "$name"          # This removes the leading slashdot
done>$ddw_data/FTP_FILE_LIST
```

Challenge is that some of the files have spaces in them (Files are coming to us from MS Windows machines) so I used `rename`

```
for name in ${sF_Array[@]}
do
   rename 's/ /_/g' "$name"  # This removes spaces in file names
   basename "$name"          # This removes the leading slashdot
done>$ddw_data/FTP_FILE_LIST
```

but it does not to work. This is what `FTP_FILE_LIST` looks like (notice 2nd and 3rd  records/filenames):

```
TCA~PRE~PREP~9939985~ONTDTVE3A~33~F~3922~R22-100~000806451655~20130819~040320.XML
J
MEM~ETT~CVT~654687-MEMTO~jgm16227~1~P~1100~R24-500~033068658187~20130813~234639.XML
J
MEM~FUN~TEST~312326-MEMTO~jgm16227~2~P~1100~R24-200~035696412416~20130813~234638.XML
J-MEM~DCA~FVT~5333131~ONTDTVD1C~1~F~3420~DECA1MR0-01~XED1B1201A3313~20130827~201916.XML
TCA~COS~COSM~95518585~ONTDTVE7A~63~F~3911~R22-300~00065881346~20130817~000300.XML
```

I want  `FTP_FILE_LIST` to look like this instead (notice 2nd and 3rd records/filenames):

```
TCA~PRE~PREP~9939985~ONTDTVE3A~33~F~3922~R22-100~000806451655~20130819~040320.XML
J_MEM~ETT~CVT~654687-MEMTO~jgm16227~1~P~1100~R24-500~033068658187~20130813~234639.XML
J_MEM~FUN~TEST~312326-MEMTO~jgm16227~2~P~1100~R24-200~035696412416~20130813~234638.XML
J-MEM~DCA~FVT~5333131~ONTDTVD1C~1~F~3420~DECA1MR0-01~XED1B1201A3313~20130827~201916.XML
TCA~COS~COSM~95518585~ONTDTVE7A~63~F~3911~R22-300~00065881346~20130817~000300.XML
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0):

`rename` will rename the actual file, not change the variable.  Use `tr` or something to fix the file names inline:

```
basename "$(echo "$name" | tr " " "_")"
```

Comment: I did not know about that. Thanks. I assumed that quoting the variable would resolve to the file name. Unfortunately, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by creating two separate tasks in my script:

1) to rename files with spaces

```
find . -type f \( ...\) | while read file
do
        target=`echo "$file" | sed 's/ /_/g'`
        mv "$file" "$target"
done
```

2) to create my file list

```
sF_Array=(` find . -type f ...  `)
sF_len=${#sF_Array[*]}
for name in ${sF_Array[@]}
do
   basename "$name"          # This removes the leading slashdot
done>$ddw_data/FTP_FILE_LIST
```

It's interesting that it works this way but does not in one single step.

Thanks for your time.